# React Native: Device Independent grid of squares with flexbox

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'd like to display the same grid with squares independently if the user has an iPad or an iPhone, growing the square sizes accordingly.

I do not want to detect the device and change the width and height of the squares based on the screen size.
Is it possible to use only the css flex capabilities of React Native?

[image: Grid Example]

Here the 
[rnplay example](https://rnplay.org/apps/A-s9xw)

Answer (score 1):

The current (0.33.0 at time of writing) [flexbox capabilities of React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html) (using `flexDirection` and `flex`) can only give you even widths or heights, but not both at the same time. Why don't you want to use [`Dimensions`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) to measure the screen size?

Comment: Dimension is what I am doing right now to enlarge the squares but it seemed to me a wrong approach to calculate fixed sizes based on screen width and height.

Comment: If you look at the comments I wrote on @kukkuz's answer, you might be able to try out using the `flexBasis` property which is on the 0.34.0-rc, but it looks like you're still going to have to manually measure 33% of width minus some margin no matter what. There is nothing wrong with manually measuring dimensions in this case, and in (mostly native) mobile development measuring dimensions is a very common practice.

Comment: @Ronnie, would you mind sharing the code of how you're doing the measurements? It could be that there is an easier way to do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a trick which allows you to actually create a grid of squares using `flexbox`- maybe you can adopt it to React Native.

**Example**:

1. First I created a `flexbox` with 3 boxes in a row that wraps into multiple rows:

   ```
   .flexbox {
     list-style: none;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
   .flexbox > * {
     margin: 5px;
     text-align: center;
     border: 1px solid red;
     flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px);
   }
   ```

   Note `flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px)` that allows to keep 3 boxes in a row- change this to accommodate more boxes. (`10px` here is the double of the margin).
2. And here is the trick that makes them squares- make a pseudo `inline-block` element which has `padding-bottom: 100%`. (If you give padding/margin in percentages, then it is always taken with respect to the width)

   ```
   .flexbox > *:before {
     content: '';
     padding-bottom: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
   }
   ```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flexbox {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexbox > * {
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px);
}
.flexbox > *:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="flexbox">
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
    <div>some text here</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like `flexBasis` was recently added to React Native but is not documented. You should try using it, however, I'm not sure how to emulate `calc(33.33% - 10px)` given that `flexBasis` requires a number as a prop.

Comment: Oh turns out `flexBasis` is on the 0.34.0-rc. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.34.0-rc.0

Comment: well, don't know much about `react native`... hope this answer helps you find a way... :)

Comment: For your info: if`flex-basis` won't work you can use `min-width: calc(33.33% - 10px)` or even `width: calc(33.33% - 10px)` too... guess `calc` can be emulated in some way...

Comment: He will most likely need to calculate the `width`.

Comment: Hey guys, please upvote if this answer helped you... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add

`aspectRatio: 1`

in the style of the component if a width or height is already set by say a `flex: 1` and it will generate the other value for you!